# Mapping specific values of an array of objects to another Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have the following two arrays

```js
let first = [
    { name: 'abc', num: 123, isPresent: true }, 
    { name: 'xyz', num: 456, isPresent: false }]

let second = []
```

How can I iterate through the `first` array and push **only** the values of `name` and `isPresent` into a new array if I need the final result to look like this?

```js
second = [{ name: 'abc', isPresent: true }, {name: 'xyz', isPresent: false }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` to iterate over the `first` array and return only the desired fields.

```js
let first = [
  { name: "abc", num: 123, isPresent: true },
  { name: "xyz", num: 456, isPresent: false },
];

let second = first.map(({ name, isPresent }) => ({ name, isPresent }));

console.log(second);
```

Comment: @MananSharma Please check if this solves your problem, and do let me know if you're facing any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) ***to create a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array*** along with [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let first = [
    { name: 'abc', num: 123, isPresent: true }, 
    { name: 'xyz', num: 456, isPresent: false }]

let second = first.map(({name, isPresent}) => ({name, isPresent}));
console.log(second);
```

Comment: The same answer was already there, why post again?